# Recieving TCP socket data by buffer

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, buffer, tcpclient

Do I have to get data from tcp socket with the buffer size? I know the data packages are divided with \n, so is there any way to get data from the server until I hit \n ?
python socket package has recv() method accepting buffer as the only parameter.

Comment: By the way, the data is a stream

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; TCP doesn’t provide any message-framing functionality.  Recv() will always just give you as many bytes as it can (up to the limit you specified) and then it is up to your code to handle those bytes appropriately regardless of how many (or how few) were passed to you by any given recv() call.

For example you might add the received bytes to the end of a buffer, then search the buffer for the first newline character; if you find one, remove it and whatever precedes it from the buffer and handle the removed text; repeat until no more new lines are found in the buffer.

Comment: Let me clarify myself. There is a stream of data, which is text only. I know there are \n's in that stream. For example:
Cloud is blue/n
grass is green/n
I love you more than anything/n
So, when I get data with recv(1024) and decode it, I see ''Cloud is bl''
If I ask for recv(2048), I see ''Cloud is blue/n Grass is''
I want to receive data by specific character, like recv("/n") so I get the data whenever tit hits the "/n"

Comment: Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Only by writing your own wrapper function around recv() to buffer the data, parse it, and split it up according by to your specification.  The BSD sockets API itself does not include that functionality.